# How to semi identify user?

Tags: javascript, cookies, ip-address

I need to detect with a "high" probability if user is the same as before, I need offer same price for him. How?

I tought I would check IP address and browser type. If it is the same was received before, then bingo.

What do you think, is it any better option? Should I use cookies? What if I would not give him the chance just by press `Clear history` to re-identify himself. At least move on other IP or start an other browser.

Do you know wether I can use `window.location.host` to get client 'IP'? Or what else?

Comment: The standard way to do this is by using [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies.

```
//Set the previous price
document.cookie = "price=5"

//Get previous price
function getCookie() {
  var name = "price";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

For more information on how to use cookies, read [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: What if I would not give him the chance just by press `Clear browser history` to re-identify himself?